# Crystal Reports 2013 How do I exclude Null Values in a Crosstab average?

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

How do I get a crosstab in Crystal Reports 2013 to exclude null values from a crosstab average?

For example

Procedure Name : OCT RETINA

Procedure Count : 8

Procedures with Completion Times Populated : 6

Summary of all 6 Completion Times : 101

I was expecting the average of the Completion Times to be calculated as 101/6. Instead, Crystal Reports is calculating the average as 101/8. It needs to be calculated as 101/6 (without counting null values in the denominator).

Adding another group is not an option because of the very specific way the values are sorted in the detail (hence a crosstab in a footer). The names of the procedures are dynamic so keeping a running total of each procedure's average completion time is not an option either.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be instead of taking the field create a formula use that in cross tab.

Create a formula @count

```
if << procedure field>>=<<your value>>
then 1
else 0
```

Now place the formula and take `sum` instead of `count`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's feedback! The answer is to use Weighted Average instead of just a plain old Average.

All I had to do was

a. Create a formula field called IncludeProcInDenominator and set the value to 
*if {Command.ProcTime} > 0 then 1* 
b. Right click on the Average Proc Time calculation in the crosstab and select *Edit Summary* 
c. When the Edit Summary dialog box appears, in the Calculate This Summary drop down, select *Weighted average with* 
d. In the dropdown box underneath that, select @IncludeProcInDenominator

In effect, the only values that are averaged are the ones where @IncludeProcInDenominator = 1

Thanks for everyone's help!